# Delete the foreign key data when the data in the foreign table is deleted

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have 2 database tables, and I want when I delete a data in the table where the foreign key is pointing (where the primary key is), the foreign key pointing to that data also be deleted.

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {

        Report report = await db.Reports
            .Include(i => i.RepFilters)
            .Where(i => i.ID == id).SingleAsync();

        db.Reports.Remove(report);

        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

The foreign key is not nullable.

[image]
(the error I get)

How to do/fix that? (help me make the right title)

Comment: You can configure cascade delete on primary table in DB Server

Comment: I want to do it without opening the SQL Server MS. I want to do it with LINQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be possible when .Net or EF generated the code for your context that the

```
.WillCascadeOnDelete()
```

was set to false, so just change it to true and try if it works.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to do it through the SQL server, you'll have to load all the child objects in the `db context` and delete them.

Comment: isn't `.Include(i => i.RepFilters)` doing that?

Comment: may be there are other child objects?

Comment: nope.. There are 2 tables: Reports and RepFilters. RepFilters has a foreign key pointing to Reports, and that foreign key is not nullable

Comment: I probably wasn't clear, you'll have to delete each of those child object and then delete the parent object followed by `save change`

Answer (score 1):

Your Foreign Key should be configured as 
    on Delete CASCADE
    on Update CASCADE.

Comment: how exactly do you mean? can you be more specific?

Comment: Review your Foreign Key.